# Using a separate user for multiple Git remotes on the same repository

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config, multiple-users

Is there a way to clone a repository, add a second remote, but use a different/separate user for that second remote automatically when pushing/pulling?

My use case is to have the remote "origin" only for pulling (actually checking out) changes with "user A" and to have remote "my-second-remote" for pulling AND pushing with "user B".

Is there a way to set up a separate user for each remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the user which is used to authenticate against each remote? Then yes — just embed the user name to the [remote's URL](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#URLS).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible in Git. Name and email are embedded in the commits.